# Extracting text from a cell in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, find-and-replace

I have a long list of items in Column A that includes a code and descriptive text. I need to separate the code from the text description.

```
 <ABC,1122, A1> - This is the text description
```

The formatting is always the same, except for the number of letters in the code, so I can't simply use the `LEN` function. I'm trying to put the code (in brackets) into column B and the text "This is..." in column C.

Any ideas on how I can go about separating this long list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
=Trim(Mid(cellref, 1, Len(cellref) - Search("-",cellref)-2)
```

As long as the formatting is the same (which you said it is), this should work fine.

Comment: This gave me the code part. However, it inspired me to look at something else and I ended up using: =RIGHT(cellref,LEN(cellref)-SEARCH("-",cellref,1)). It works fine with another column next to it to TRIM some loose spaces. Thanks for you help.

Comment: As an FYI, you don't need to specify the 'start' value for the SEARCH function. You could just do SEARCH("-",cellref)

Answer (score 1):

In Excel VBA, use `InStr()` to find the dash `"-"` position, then use that position information in `Left()` and `Right()` to extract the two parts of the string.  Reading column A into an array of strings first will possibly speed things up.

Comment: Unable to find InStr as a formula, so wasn't able to test your suggestion.

Comment: @Mike It's VBA, sorry I didn't specify.

Answer (score 1):

To get the description:

```
=MID(A1,FIND("-",A1,1)+2,LEN(A1))
```

To extract the code part:

```
=MID(A1,1,FIND(">",A1,1))
```

where A1 contains your string. Wrap them in TRIM to remove leading and trailing spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just use the "Text-to-columns" feature under "Data", and split it using the "-" as your delimiter?